# what is the @number in the dumpbin exports output

Tags: c++, windows, dll, export, dumpbin

Using `DUMPBIN` on a C++ .DLL (or IMPLIB .LIB file) with /EXPORTS or /IMPORTS I see syntax in the output like the following:

```
Exports

ordinal    name

      _CloseConduit@4
      _ConduitPort
      _GetConduitVersion@4
      _GetStatusConduit@8
      _GetTimeout@0
      _OpenConduit@4
```

I could not find anywhere a definition of what the `@n` designation means.  I finally have concluded that it's the number of bytes of argument data, but it leaves me a little nervous depending on inference from a few examples.  Can anyone point to a reference, or say with any authority, what the number here means?

Comment: It's [C++ name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: The names are decorated with `extern "C"` so it's not straight mangling per se.

Comment: Are these class members? `extern "C"` is ignored if so.

Comment: @richp:   In Windows, C functions can get "decorated" to indicate calling convention.  RogerRowland's link above actually discusses that, briefly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct to conclude that `@n` indicates the number of bytes for the function parameters. You can find the relevant MSDN documentation [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) and [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx).

In particular, that is how MSVC decorates `extern "C" __stdcall` functions in C++. Note that this is technically implementation defined and other compilers do decorate this differently.

For example, MinGW-gcc decorates it *without* the leading underscore. Embarcadero's compiler(formerly Borland) does not decorate `__stdcall` functions at all while Digital Mar's compiler uses the same decoration scheme as MSVC.